# How to resolve TypeError:s objext can not be iterpreted as an int

Tags: python, numpy, error-handling

I am trying to use the following code to calculate the distance whenever I click the mouse, but I am receiving this error: TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
I have tried to follow this solution but didn't work with me: sudo pip install -U numpy==1.11.0

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor 
from numpy import random 
import numpy as np 
#import pyautogui 
import mplcursors
from math import sqrt

x1, y1=random.rand(2,100)
x2, y2=random.rand(2,100)

fig, ax= plt.subplots()
p, = plt.plot(x1,y1, 'o')
p2, = plt.plot( x2,y2, 'o')
ax.set_xlabel('X-axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis')




cursor=Cursor(ax, horizOn=True, vertOn=True, color='blue', linewidth=1.0)
def onclick(event):
    z1, r1 = event.xdata, event.ydata
    print(z1, r1)
    #return z1,r1

    a1= int(z1,r1)
    p1 = a1.split(",")
    p2 = a1.split(",")

    distance = sqrt( ((int(p1[0])-int(p2[0]))**2)+((int(p1[1])-int(p2[1]))**2) )

    print("distance between ",p1,"and", p2, "is",distance) 


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

mplcursors.cursor(hover=True) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: post the full error message *including the stack trace*

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to achieve. `z1` and `r1` are both floating point values, not strings or lists. You're getting a single coordinate back from the click event, so I'm not understanding where you expect two points to come from via `p1` and `p2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you would like the capability to click two points, and calculate the distance between them once the second point has been clicked. I modified your code to give you the ability to store class variables which you'll need to keep track of the first and second click events.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor
from numpy import random
import mplcursors
from math import sqrt


class DistancePlot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x1, self.y1 = random.rand(2,100)
        self.x2, self.y2 = random.rand(2,100)

        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.p = plt.plot(self.x1, self.y1, 'o')
        self.p2 = plt.plot(self.x2, self.y2, 'o')
        self.ax.set_xlabel('X-axis')
        self.ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis')

        self.d1 = (0.0, 0.0)
        self.d2 = (0.0, 0.0)

        self.first_click = True

        cursor=Cursor(self.ax, horizOn=True, vertOn=True, color='blue', linewidth=1.0)

        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.onclick)

        mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)
        plt.show()

    def onclick(self, event):
        z1, r1 = event.xdata, event.ydata
        print(z1, r1)

        if self.first_click:
            self.first_click = False
            self.d1 = (z1, r1)
        else:
            self.first_click = True
            self.d2 = (z1, r1)
            distance = sqrt((((self.d1[0]) - (self.d2[0])) ** 2) + (((self.d1[1]) - (self.d2[1])) ** 2))
            print("distance between ", self.d1, "and", self.d2, "is", distance)

dp = DistancePlot()
```

This can be cleaned up significantly, but I used much of your original code for the sake of clarity regarding your original problem.

Output:

```
0.428774046828733 0.7279552011765266
0.8336888592710245 0.383512252192596
distance between  (0.428774046828733, 0.7279552011765266) and (0.8336888592710245, 0.383512252192596) is 0.5315984861151531
0.18538262951369436 0.6425804531377746
0.3933716588556365 0.40117599316613084
distance between  (0.18538262951369436, 0.6425804531377746) and (0.3933716588556365, 0.40117599316613084) is 0.3186464335604656
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code seems to be working for me, or what is exactly the problem?
[image]

Is it not the output that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: This should have been a comment to the OP. The user needs to click in order to trigger the error. Also, answering a question with "what is exactly the problem" is not an answer at all. Hope this helps and keep working towards contributing to the community! :)

Comment: I was trying to catch return the mouse click and then calculate the distance between the two clicks, thankfully other users helped me